# Scrollview to PDF View giving blur in Android

Tags: android, pdf, scroll, screenshot, blur

I have long scrollview almost 50+ fields.

I'm converting that scrollview to pdf view. pdf also creating all done. 
But pdf file showing data is blur (too blur).

With some merging, I provided some reference image (I mean output image).

[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjaSF.png)

My code:

```
private void takeScreenShot() {

    try {

    //here getScroll is my scrollview id

    View u = ((Activity) mContext).findViewById(R.id.getScroll);

    ScrollView z = (ScrollView) ((Activity) mContext).findViewById(R.id.getScroll);
    int totalHeight = z.getChildAt(0).getHeight();
    int totalWidth = z.getChildAt(0).getWidth();

    Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromView(u,totalHeight,totalWidth);

    Image image;

    //Save bitmap
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Folder/";
    String fileName = "report1.pdf";

    File dir = new File(path);
    if (!dir.exists())
        dir.mkdirs();

    Log.v("PDFCreator", "PDF Path: " + path);

    File myPath = new File(path, fileName);



        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 10, stream);
        image = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
        image.setAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
        Document document = new Document(image);
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(myPath));
        document.open();
        document.add(image);
        document.close();


    } catch (Exception i1) {
        i1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Any help?

Comment: i think you have to enable drawingcache of Scrollview and after completing whole process disable drawingcache

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
    View u = ((Activity) mContext).findViewById(R.id.getScroll);
    u.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    u.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(u.getDrawingCache());
    bitmap.setHasAlpha(true); //important for PNG

  ---------------DO SAVE WORK-----------------

    v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

And at

```
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 10, stream);
```

change 10 to 90 or 100. it is Image Quality.

Or just change in your code to higher quality.

Try another solution:

```
ScrollView v= (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.getScroll);

int height = v.getChildAt(0).getHeight()
int width = v.getWidth()
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
v.layout(0, 0, v.getLayoutParams().width, v.getLayoutParams().height);
v.draw(c);

bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
```

Comment: sorry even though blur

Comment: just try to save above bitmap to image to see if any blur happen or not

Comment: did you increase quality in your code? and try to switch PNG instead of JPEG

Comment: image also coming blur sir

Comment: bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);

Comment: ScrollView z = (ScrollView) ((Activity) mContext).findViewById(R.id.getScroll);
            int totalHeight = z.getChildAt(0).getHeight();
            int totalWidth = z.getChildAt(0).getWidth();

if if didnt give those image displaying empty

in your code not there noH these

Comment: i mean use your code just change quality. if same problem then your scrollview or views inside it causing problem

Comment: if i use only this Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(u.getDrawingCache());-->diaplay image is empty

Comment: in activity screen its displaying perfect

after changing quality 10 to 100 some thing blur decreased even though no clarity

Comment: did you try another solution?

Answer (score 0):

Take a screen shot using this code and

```
   ScrollView iv = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
            iv.getChildAt(0).getWidth(),
            iv.getChildAt(0).getHeight(),
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);
    c.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    iv.getChildAt(0).draw(c);

    // Do whatever you want with your bitmap
    saveBitmap(bitmap);
```

and save the bitmap as a image

```
public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {

    File imagePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/screenshot.png");
    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be late but anyway. Use png format instead, increase the quality to 100 and replace

```
View u = ((Activity) mContext).findViewById(R.id.getScroll);
```

with

```
View u = ((Activity) mContext).findViewById(R.id.yourfirstscrollviewchild);
```

Thatll do the trick.